# Dafny verification fails "post condition might not hold"

Tags: algorithm, verification, dafny, formal-verification, formal-methods

i am new here (my first question)
We are supposed to use a given code from a website and convert it into dafny code.
The code logic itself is supposedly good.
When i try to convert the code in dafny it complains that the postconditions might not hold:

it specifically complains about the following lines:

`ensures isMaxHeap(heapifiedArray)` in the method `BuildMaxHeap`
`ensures maxHeapPrperty(arr, i) == true` in the method `MaxHeapify`
`assert maxHeapPrperty(arr, i);` in the method `MaxHeapify`

What am i doing wrong and how can i rectify this? I attempted multiple times to rewrite the `maxHeapPrperty` method thinking maybe its the crux of the issue. But, it did not work.

I am pretty new to dafny so I am sorry if this question is a little too basic, i am trying to learn, i hit a brick wall and i cannot seem to be to crack this.

```
predicate isMaxHeap(arr : array<nat>)
requires arr.Length >= 0
reads arr
{
  forall i : int :: 0 <= i < arr.Length/2-1 ==> maxHeapPrperty(arr, i)
}

predicate maxHeapPrperty(arr : array<nat>, i : int)
requires arr.Length >= 0
requires 0 <= i < arr.Length
reads arr
{
  if (2*i +2 >= arr.Length && 2*i +1 >= arr.Length) then true
  else if (2*i +2 >= arr.Length) then arr[i] >= arr[2*i +1]
  else arr[i] >= arr[2*i +1] && arr[i] >= arr[2*i +2]
  
}
method BuildMaxHeap(arr : array<nat>) returns(heapifiedArray : array<nat>)
requires arr.Length > 3
modifies arr
ensures isMaxHeap(heapifiedArray)
{
  var i := (arr.Length/2)-1;
  while (2 == 0) {

          MaxHeapify(arr, i);
    i := i-1;

  }
  heapifiedArray := arr;
}



method MaxHeapify(arr: array<nat>, i: int)
  requires arr.Length > 0
  requires 0 <= i < arr.Length
  modifies arr
  decreases arr.Length - i
  ensures maxHeapPrperty(arr, i) == true
{
  var largest: int := i; // Initialize largest as root
  var l: int := 2 * i + 1; // left = 2*i + 1
  var r: int := 2 * i + 2; // right = 2*i + 2


  if l < arr.Length && arr[l] > arr[largest] {
    largest := l;
  }


  if r < arr.Length && arr[r] > arr[largest] {
    largest := r;
  }

  assert largest == i || (largest == l && arr[largest] >= arr[i]) || (largest == r && arr[largest] >= arr[i]);


  if largest != i {
    swap(arr, i, largest);


    MaxHeapify(arr, largest);

  }

  assert maxHeapPrperty(arr, i);
}

method swap(arr : array<nat>, i : int, j : int) 
requires arr.Length > 0
requires 0 <= i < arr.Length
requires 0 <= j < arr.Length
modifies arr
ensures arr[j] == old(arr[i])
ensures arr[i] == old(arr[j])
{
  var temp := arr[i];
  arr[i] := arr[j];
  arr[j] := temp;

}
```

I tried to convert a code from Java to dafny, the code's logic is supposed to be sound, The code does indeed produce a maxHeap, however when i try to inssert the preconditions and the post conditions, it complains, i do not know why.

Comment: Dafny cannot prove code is correct just by implementing the code. You must also specify invariants and pre and post conditions which show that your code is correct. In any situation with a loop or recursion you must use induction to prove that it is true. Some examples https://dafny.org/blog/2023/10/11/insertion-sort/ and https://github.com/hath995/dafny/blob/main/ProgramProofs/ch15.dfy